# Testing authorized API calls on FrontEnd

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, jestjs, frontend

I have a react app, in which I have defined functions for APIs, so that I can call these functions where I need.

Now the thing is I want to write tests for these API calls. My API function use [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) internally for executing requests. In the app I use Axios Interceptors to add auth token to these requests, and now I want a clean way to test such authorized APIs which needs tokens in their headers.

My question is how can I use test these authorized API function without disturbing my design.
Here is a sample API function which I want to test, it needs auth token in the header:

```
export const delete_store = (id) => {
  return Axios.delete(`api/example/url/${id}`);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass headers as second argument.

`Axios.delete(URL, {headers: { auth: token }})`

Comment: I am using interceptors for my requests. So I don't need to do this in my function above. The problem is I want to test above function, so how can I use interceptor for this case?